# Как не потеряться в «большом» проекте? (карта веб сервиса + клиента)

Tags: uml, планирование, блок-схема

Как вы документируете, планируете, рисуете общую схему проекта, чтобы не держать всё в голове и в любой момент вернуться, и быстро въехать?

Напр. относительно простой веб-сервис и его клиент. Простой протокол их общения для CRUD и ещё чуть-чуть. Сервис подключается ещё к Амазоновским сервисам для хранения данных. Клиент внутри себя имеет мультитредовые цепочки событий.

Одна и та же сущность немного по-разному представляется внутри клиента (`ActionScript`), в сервере (`php`) и хранится в БД (`Amazon SimpleDB`) — различия типа пустой текстовой строки `VS`. `null`, строка/массив/сериализованный объект.

Стоит это пытаться уместить в одной схеме, или разбить отдельно протоколы, отдельно алгоритмы и события внутри клиента, отдельно схема классов?

Далёк от планирования и раньше особо не заморачивался рисованием диаграмм, но тут впервые ощущаю потребность в какой-то системе.

Поделитесь Вашей?

Comment: @SilverIce - Где бы посмотреть примеры?

Comment: @sergiks, представьте карту мира, потом карту континента, потом карту отдельной страны и карту острова. Масштабирование - это раз. Но иногда бывают разные схемы, взависимости от исполняемых функций. Это - два. Но как замечено ниже - это делается если это нужно )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть классика, предложенная ещё со времен ООП: многоуровневая схема.

Есть общая схема проекта (на уровне модулей).

Есть внутренняя схема модулей (можно несколько детализаций, пока не удовлетворит).

Если нужно - рисуется схема вызовов.

Если нужно делает таблица (много таблиц) о правилах обмена данными.